# How to tell when Microsoft Print to PDF printer driver is finished?

Tags: c++, c, winapi, printing

I needed a cheap way for my application to create a PDF file. So I'm using the print functions of the Windows API directly (`CreateDC()`, `StartDoc()`, `StartPage()`, `EndPage()`, `EndDoc()`, etc.), and selecting the *Microsoft Print to PDF* printer driver.

In addition, I found that if I set the `lpszOutput` member of the `DOCINFO`structure to a filename, the driver will write the PDF file to the named file without prompting the user for a name.

So far, so good. But how do I know when the PDF file has been created? There are spooler APIs, but the driver isn't necessarily done just because the spooler is done. Or I could create a loop that looks for the file, but of course it will exist before it is actually done. I also thought about trying to put a lock on the file in my loop, which should fail if the file doesn't exist yet or is still being written to.

But I can't help but wonder if there's a more direct way to know when the PDF file is ready.

Comment: I'm assuming you're using the GDI Print API. When are calling `ClosePrinter()` ?

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: No, I don't, but I'm not calling `OpenPrinter()`. Either way, the PDF is being created just fine. My issue is knowing when it's finished being created.

Comment: @4386427: I know there are some free libraries out there, but most of them seem old and maybe outdated. That question is from 11 years ago. I thought by using the printer driver, it should be pretty reliable and stay current. It's working fine. It's just that my code doesn't know when the file is ready.

Comment: The thing is, how you monitor a print job depends on how you create the print job. So which print API are you using? XPS? PrintDocumentPackage?

Comment: with out code, we can only guess.  Please post a [mcve] so we can help you debug the problem

Comment: @MarkBenningfield: I'm using the Windows API directly (`CreateDC()`, `StartDoc()`, `StartPage()`, `EndPage()`, `EndDoc()`, etc.).

Comment: @user3629249: There is no problem to debug. I'm wondering how you would detect when a print device has finished with the document.

Comment: Ok, that's the GDI Print API. Use this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/160129/how-to-get-the-status-of-a-printer-and-a-print-job) that uses GDI Print to check the status of print jobs on a printer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the GDI Print API (wingdi.h), then this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/160129/how-to-get-the-status-of-a-printer-and-a-print-job) shows the sample code used to query the status of print jobs on a printer.

I'm including the code from the link, but you might want to read the article as well.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <wingdi.h>

BOOL GetJobs(HANDLE hPrinter,        /* Handle to the printer. */

             JOB_INFO_2 **ppJobInfo, /* Pointer to be filled.  */
             int *pcJobs,            /* Count of jobs filled.  */
             DWORD *pStatus)         /* Print Queue status.    */

{

  DWORD               cByteNeeded,
    nReturned,
    cByteUsed;
  JOB_INFO_2          *pJobStorage = NULL;
  PRINTER_INFO_2       *pPrinterInfo = NULL;

  /* Get the buffer size needed. */
  if (!GetPrinter(hPrinter, 2, NULL, 0, &cByteNeeded)) {
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER)
      return FALSE;
  }

  pPrinterInfo = (PRINTER_INFO_2 *)malloc(cByteNeeded);
  if (!(pPrinterInfo))
    /* Failure to allocate memory. */
    return FALSE;

  /* Get the printer information. */
  if (!GetPrinter(hPrinter,
                  2,
                  (LPSTR)pPrinterInfo,
                  cByteNeeded,
                  &cByteUsed)) {
    /* Failure to access the printer. */
    free(pPrinterInfo);
    pPrinterInfo = NULL;
    return FALSE;
  }

  /* Get job storage space. */
  if (!EnumJobs(hPrinter,
                0,
                pPrinterInfo->cJobs,
                2,
                NULL,
                0,
                (LPDWORD)&cByteNeeded,
                (LPDWORD)&nReturned)) {
    if (GetLastError() != ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER) {
      free(pPrinterInfo);
      pPrinterInfo = NULL;
      return FALSE;
    }
  }

  pJobStorage = (JOB_INFO_2 *)malloc(cByteNeeded);
  if (!pJobStorage) {
    /* Failure to allocate Job storage space. */
    free(pPrinterInfo);
    pPrinterInfo = NULL;
    return FALSE;
  }

  ZeroMemory(pJobStorage, cByteNeeded);

  /* Get the list of jobs. */
  if (!EnumJobs(hPrinter,
                0,
                pPrinterInfo->cJobs,
                2,
                (LPBYTE)pJobStorage,
                cByteNeeded,
                (LPDWORD)&cByteUsed,
                (LPDWORD)&nReturned)) {
    free(pPrinterInfo);
    free(pJobStorage);
    pJobStorage = NULL;
    pPrinterInfo = NULL;
    return FALSE;
  }

  /*
  *  Return the information.
  */
  *pcJobs = nReturned;
  *pStatus = pPrinterInfo->Status;
  *ppJobInfo = pJobStorage;
  free(pPrinterInfo);

  return TRUE;

}

BOOL IsPrinterError(HANDLE hPrinter) {

  JOB_INFO_2  *pJobs;
  int         cJobs,
    i;
  DWORD       dwPrinterStatus;

  /*
  *  Get the state information for the Printer Queue and
  *  the jobs in the Printer Queue.
  */
  if (!GetJobs(hPrinter, &pJobs, &cJobs, &dwPrinterStatus))
    return FALSE;

  /*
  *  If the Printer reports an error, believe it.
  */
  if (dwPrinterStatus &
    (PRINTER_STATUS_ERROR |
     PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_JAM |
     PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_OUT |
     PRINTER_STATUS_PAPER_PROBLEM |
     PRINTER_STATUS_OUTPUT_BIN_FULL |
     PRINTER_STATUS_NOT_AVAILABLE |
     PRINTER_STATUS_NO_TONER |
     PRINTER_STATUS_OUT_OF_MEMORY |
     PRINTER_STATUS_OFFLINE |
     PRINTER_STATUS_DOOR_OPEN)) {
    free(pJobs);
    return TRUE;
  }

  /*
  *  Find the Job in the Queue that is printing.
  */
  for (i = 0; i < cJobs; i++) {
    if (pJobs[i].Status & JOB_STATUS_PRINTING) {
      /*
      *  If the job is in an error state,
      *  report an error for the printer.
      *  Code could be inserted here to
      *  attempt an interpretation of the
      *  pStatus member as well.
      */
      if (pJobs[i].Status &
        (JOB_STATUS_ERROR |
         JOB_STATUS_OFFLINE |
         JOB_STATUS_PAPEROUT |
         JOB_STATUS_BLOCKED_DEVQ)) {
        free(pJobs);
        return TRUE;
      }
    }
  }

  /*
  *  No error condition.
  */
  free(pJobs);
  return FALSE;

}
```